# Generating one random number from given input [C++]

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int n;
int *array;
array= new int[n];
cout<<"Masukkan ukuran array"<< endl;
cin >> n;
cout << "Masukkan nilai array" << endl;

for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];
}

cout << "hasil array adalah"<< endl;
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout<<array[i]<< " ";
}
cout << endl<< "hasil urut adalah"<< endl;
for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if (array[j]<array [i])
        {
            int temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]= temp;
        }
        else;
    }
}

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout << array[i]<< " ";
}




return 0;

}
```

i'm trying to generate a single random number from the inputted value for example i input 1,3,6,8 to my array and im trying to figure it out how to generate a random number from given input so the output will be 3 or 6 or 8 etc

Comment: This code won't be compile ! after that your question is not clear , do you want to generate a  random number from your array ?

Comment: The _order_ in which you do things makes a difference: you cannot use `n` before you ask the user what it is. (You should be using a `std::vector` though.) Use `std::uniform_int_distribution` to get a random index into your array, then output the element of the array at that index.

Comment: yes i want to generate random number from my array @Mahdy.n

Answer (score 0):

To get a random number from an array do something like this:

```
// Do this part once in the application.
std::random_device seedGenerator;
std::mt19937       randomDevice(seedGenerator());

// This describes the type of random numbers you want
// You can create one of these each time or re-use them
// as needed.
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, n);

// Now get a random number by passing the random number device
// to the distribution so it can generate a clean number in the
// correct range you want.
int randomIndex = dist(randomDevice);
int randomValue = array[randomIndex];

// Output the value.
std::cout << randomValue << "\n";
```